# Does simple date format support this conversion?

Tags: java, date

I am getting this Date as String

```
String str = "Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)";
```

How to convert this Date Object into the format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH24:Mi:ss`?

I have not seen any example using SimpleDateFormat with this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse it into a `Date` first using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str);
```

Then, you can format it using another `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

```
String str2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, I however wonder where the original string is coming from. It look much like the result of `date.toString()`. Are you sure you're doing things the right way? Date should be stored and transferred as `java.util.Date` and not as `java.lang.String`. You should only convert it to `String` at exactly the point whenever you want to *display* it to the enduser.